# the lifetime of global objectives

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Suppose the learner takes course A. A global objective (g-obj-1) is created by this course. The learner triggers an Exit All or Suspend All navigation request and returns to LMS. The learner is deleted by the LMS's admin. Now, what should be happened to the global objective (g-obj-1)? Should it be deleted or should it be set to default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tracking data is saved in a database for each learner using his username and password when he logs in to the system. If a learner is deleted from the LMS, everything  related to him is gone including global objectives or any other data.